# What is the difference between ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso and ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64+mac.iso?

Tags: live-usb, mac, macbook, macbook-pro

My current assumption is that the mac version has drivers particular to the mac ecosystem?

Does that mean that I can't create a live system with the non mac iso to boot my mac over USB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"This image is adjusted to work properly on Mac systems" is what I found at http://releases.ubuntu.com/saucy/ for the ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64+mac.iso

Answer (score 2):

I can't find the source link at the moment, but I've read that the Mac images disable (U)EFI booting. Apple's EFI implementation doesn't play nice with Ubuntu (well, anything not OS X), so the amd64+mac images only support booting via BIOS, which Macs support for booting Windows via Boot Camp.